# Writing a SQL query that returns tuples

Tags: mysql, sql

You are given a relation R with N columns of the same type. Write an SQL query that returns
the tuples (perhaps more than one) having the minimum number of different values. The solution
should have size polynomial in N and use aggregation in an essential way.

Examples:

1. R1 = {t1 : (a, a, b),(t2 : (b, a, c)}: the result is t1.
2. R2 = {t1 : (a, a, b),(t2 : (b, a, c), t3 : (b, b, b)}: the result is t3.

A part of the solution is devising a way to uniquely identify tuples without introducing the
notion of a tuple identifier.

I can't grasp the tuple concept.

Comment: N can be any value

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. Could you edit your example?

Comment: What do you need clarification on?

Comment: Or you can help me with this sql query?,,,,,,,,, Employee(Ename,Salary),,,,,,,,
Project(Pname,Agency,Budget),,,,,,,,,,,
Assign(Pname,Ename),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
   For every project, compute the number of projects whose budget is higher,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Find the projects with the budget lower than the average project budget at the same
agency

Comment: Employee , Projects and Assign are tables @GenWan

Comment: "Tuple" is the technical term for what you may think about as a "row". You should have learned it as part of relational algebra (usually before actually doing sql, maybe reread that part in your script). To translate your task: you shall write a query that, for the 2nd example, returns 1 row with 3 values `b`, `b` and `b`. You are supposed to use aggregation (`group by`) and are not allowed to add an row number/autoincrement or similar. Noone here will do your homework for you though, but you can add your attempted solution/what you have tried and ask a more specific question if you are stuck.

Comment: How do i go by starting it?

Comment: @PariSherpa I will suggest you start with building the sample data and try something you learned from the class recently. If you are stuck anywhere, please add them into your post (not in the comment).

Comment: @PariSherpa The first question is not an easy question. Take some time to think about it. For the second question, it is better to ask separately. Please remember to try something before you ask questions here. A lot of people will be glad to help you.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "without using tuple identifier"?